# How can I check an instance's type in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unwind-segue

I want to use an unwind segue to navigate from the current `UIViewController` to the second presenting `UIViewController`:

```
let unwindDestinationViewController = self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!
                    switch unwindDestinationViewController{
                    case is UIViewControllerSubclass:
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToUIViewControllerSubclass", sender: self)
                        break
                    default:
                        break
                    }
```

However this does not work. I also tried changing the `case` statement to `UIViewControllerSubclass.Type` but it gave me an error: `cast from UIViewController to unrelated type UIViewControllerSubclass always fails.`

I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: When you say your code above **does not work**.  What do you mean?  Try printing out the type of `unwindDestinationViewController` with `print(type(of: unwindDestinationViewController))` to see what it really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct for checking the type:

```
case is UIViewControllerSubclass:
```

Another way to test the class:

```
case let vc as UIViewControllerSubclass:
```

which is helpful if you need to access a method or property specific to that class.

If you don't need to use `vc` then just do:

```
case _ as UIViewControllerSubclass:
```

---

You could just use an `if` statement here:

```
if unwindDestinationViewController is UIViewControllerSubclass {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToUIViewControllerSubclass", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: I could use an if statement but I have 5 different  view controllers to check against, it will look messy. The source of the problem was not the switch statement. The `unwindDestinationViewController` view controller was nested in two layers of `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController'. After some casting I got it to work. Both your solution and mine worked in this scenario. Thank you.